# Question about complex path integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$f(z) = \int_{z_0}^z \frac{d\zeta}{\zeta^{1/2}} $$

where the integral taken over any path in $\mathbb{C}-\{iy :y \le 0\}$
(Since it is simply connected and $\zeta^{1/2}=e^{\frac12\log{z}}$ is holomorphic in that region.) In my book(Stein) the following is stated but I cannot understand why. Could anyone explain it?

> Since $\zeta^{-1/2}$ is integrable near $0$, $f$ is continuous at
>   $0$, and this implies that the integral can be taken along any path in
>   $\mathbb{C}-\{iy :y \lt 0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a path that includes $0$, you can do an improper integral, and integrate along the path, excluding a small $\epsilon$-neighbourhood around $0$.  You will find that the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ will exist.